# Eclipse Consolas Font Rendering in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, eclipse, openjdk

I'm using the Consolas font for eclipse. Size 9.8 on windows and 9.6 on Ubuntu.

Ubuntu Left, Windows Right:

[image: Ubuntu Left, Windows Right]

I have Ubuntu 16.04, infinality and Eclipse PDT Neon. Also did this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:no1wantdthisname/openjdk-fontfix
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

also tried OracleJDK but the result was the same as openjdk.

How can i make my Eclipse Ubuntu font rendering like Eclipse Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found how to do it! Set Ubuntu font Hinting FULL and infinality to the debug.